# Solving a cubical nonlinear matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to solve an matrix optimization problem. The stationary equation drawn from the opt problem is to find the solution for $X$ of the following nonlinear matrix equation:

$AXX^TAX-AXB+C=0$

where $A$, $B$, $C$ are known. $A$ and $B$ are symmetric.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the original matrix optimization problem? Solving the equation you show may not be the best way. Among other considerations, the equation may have solutions which are not even local minima, let alone global minima, of the optimization problem.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The original matrix optimization problem is $f_X=||X^TAX-B||^2_F+\mathrm{tr}left(X^TC\right)$. I tried the method provided by greg and it works well.

Comment: The 2nd term appears to be $X^TC$, which is not a scalar, so doesn't make sense. Perhaps in your typing you forgot a norm applied to it?  In any event, you will most likely be better off applying a numerical optimization to the original optimization problem, rather than a nonlinear equation solver to its gradient.

Comment: There is a trace operation on $X^TC$, so it is a scalar. Yeah you are right, we can use a number of gradient-free optimizers to solve the original optimization problem directly. However, the computational efficiency should be taken into account. Thus, a local optimum provided by such gradient-based iterative method is acceptable. :)

Comment: I missed the tr lurking in there. I am not suggesting using a gradient-free optimizer.  Use a gradient-based optimizer applied to the original optimization problem. Don't solve gradient =- 0.

Comment: Got it! I gonna try a gradient-based solver and compare its performance with the algorithm provided by greg. To make a fair a comparison, I will adopt the same initial guess for $X$. Thank you all the same for your valuable suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2):

We want to find a root of the matrix function $F(X)=0$ where
$$\eqalign{
 F &= AXX^TAX - AXB + C \\
}$$
Calculate the differential
$$\eqalign{
dF &= A\,dX\,X^TAX + AX\,dX^TAX + AXX^TA\,dX - A\,dX\,B \\
}$$
Then vectorize the matrices, and calculate the Jacobian
$$\eqalign{
 f &= {\rm vec}(F) \\
df &= {\rm vec}(dF) \\
  &= (X^TA^TX\otimes A)dx + (X^TA^T\otimes AX)P\,dx
   + (I\otimes AXX^TA)dx - (B^T\otimes A)dx \\
  &= \Big((X^TA^TX\otimes A) + (X^TA^T\otimes AX)P
   + (I\otimes AXX^TA) - (B^T\otimes A)\Big)dx \\
  &= J\,dx \\
}$$
where $P$ is the permutation matrix required to vectorize $X^T,\;$ i.e.
$${\rm vec}(X^T) = P\,{\rm vec}(X)\\$$

Now apply Newton's insight and solve for the $dx$ which produces $\,df=-f$
$$\eqalign{
J\,dx &= -f \qquad\implies\quad dx &= -J^{-1}f \\
}$$
which suggests the following iterative scheme
$$\eqalign{
F_k &= F(X_k) \\
f_k &= {\rm vec}(F_k)\\
x_k &= {\rm vec}(X_k) \\
J_k &= (X_k^TA^TX_k\otimes A) + (X_k^TA^T\otimes AX_k)P 
     + (I\otimes AX_kX_k^TA) - (B^T\otimes A) \\
x_{k+1} &= x_k - J_k^{-1}f_k \\
X_{k+1} &= {\rm Reshape}(x_{k+1}) \\\\
}$$
This is just the basic algorithm. To improve its convergence you'll probably need to consider techniques like line-searches, trust-regions, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried your algorithm and found that it can efficiently converge to a local optimum. Honestly, I really appreciate you kind help regarding my question. :) This problem is a key step in my research work. Such iterative method is very powerful, as it can be generalized to solve a wide variety of matrix equations.

Comment: +1 But (now that the original optimization problem has (sort of) been posted, will most likely be better off applying a numerical optimization to the original optimization problem, rather than a nonlinear equation solver to its gradient.